# Как вывести результат викторины/теста сразу, чтобы оно появилось снизу

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wp-plugin

У меня есть плагин на WP, который создает тесты на странице. И после прохождения текста, ответ он выдает на отдельную страницу. А как сделать чтобы ответ выводился сразу? Я так понял надо изменять сам плагин изнутри. Но я не знаю что именно отвечает за вывод результата. После нажатия на кнопку "получить ответ" работает PHP или JS? Чтобы знать где копаться. Если что, плагин называется "QUIZ MASTER NEXT"

Comment: Это серьёзная работа, по переделке плагина. Вам надо найти исполнителя на платной основе.

Comment: Ну я же не весь плагин переделать хочу, а лишь одну из его символов. Я думал это займет всего лишь пару десятков строчек кода

Comment: и для пары десятков строк кода понадобится исполнитель

Comment: Для того, чтобы написать даже пару строк, надо разобраться в коде плагина целиком. Здесь этого никто делать не будет.